# Protractor - Jasmine - TypeError: expect is not a function

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have defined the use of Jasmine in my conf.js file

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
    },
```

And I am using the following code to click a button on a page and check for text.

```
    element(by.css('.btn.btn-success.btn-lg')).click();

    console.log('Wait 2 seconds');
    browser.sleep(2000);
    console.log('After wait');
    // question 1
    var expectedString = "Step 1 of 10";

    var actualString =  element(by.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/section[1]/app-root[1]/app-pay-only[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2[1]')).getText().then(function(actualString) {
        return actualString;
    });
    console.log('here\'s the expect');
    expect(actualString).toContain(expectedString);
```

However, I get a failure saying "expect is not a function" and when I am looking at the test run, I can see that the button isn't being pressed (so the page doesn't navigate.)  If I comment out the expect, then the page will navigate as normal.  I cannot see any reason why the click event would fail (I have even put in sleeps to see what is going on)

The stacktrace will be below - can anyone see anything to shed some light on this?

```
 Message:
   Failed: expect is not a function
 Stack:
   TypeError: expect is not a function
       at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\Desktop\protractor\LA1-311\end_to_end.js:78:9)
       at C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
       at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
       at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
       at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
       at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
       at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
       at asyncRun (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2974:25)
       at C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
       at <anonymous>
   From: Task: Run it("Must allow working end to end") in control flow
       at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
       at C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:64:48
       at ControlFlow.emit (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
       at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2674:10)
       at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2599:53)
   From asynchronous test:
   Error
       at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\Desktop\protractor\LA1-311\end_to_end.js:63:5)
       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph.Adams\Desktop\protractor\LA1-311\end_to_end.js:14:1)
       at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you are getting your variable for the expect is very different. I am not sure if it is the issue, but I have never seen it done that way. Try this:

```
var expectedString = "Step 1 of 10";
var elem = element(by.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/section[1]/app-root[1]/app-pay-only[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2[1]'));
expect(elem.getText()).toContain(expectedString);
```

Comment: @Gunderson - tried using your code and the exact same result is happening.  Also tried yong suggestion and changed to jasmine2 in my conf.js file and also the same result.

Comment: @yong - tried your suggestion also and the behaviour hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do a quick try as below: 
1. comment all lines after `console.log('After wait');`  
2. add a new line `expect('Test abc').toContain('abc')` at the end ,

If you still get same error, 
  check your whole script to find you assign other value to `expect` or not. 
(like expect=xxx or global.expect=xxxx)

If you not get same error, maybe your protractor version greater than 3.0 (I don't remember the exact version), you have to use jasmine2,  jasmine1 is not supported in high protractor.

Easy to verify it by change framework in conf file to `jasmine2`

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
```

Pleae give your package.json, so that we can know what dependecy you used and their version.